# method always return null when trying to find the first non-repeating character in a String

Tags: java, string, hashmap, character

I am trying to output the first non-repeating character in a string. However I am not sure what is wrong in my method as it always returns null. any hint is really welcomed.

```
public static char findRepeating(String s){

        HashMap<Character, Integer> charCount= new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry: charCount.entrySet()){
            entry.setValue(0);
        }
        int count=0;
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if (charCount.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){
                count=charCount.get(s.charAt(i));
                charCount.put(s.charAt(i), count++);
            }

        }
        for (Character ch:charCount.keySet()){
            if (charCount.get(ch)==0){
                return ch;
            }
        }
        return '\0';
    }
```

Comment: In a totally different context.. Java strings are not terminated by `\0` character. Also please edit your question's title to reflect your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that this loop does nothing

```
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry: charCount.entrySet()){
        entry.setValue(0);
    }
```

since the Map is empty.

As a result, `if (charCount.containsKey(s.charAt(i)))` is always false. You should add an else clause to initialize the count to 1 if the key is not found :

```
        if (charCount.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){
            count=charCount.get(s.charAt(i));
            charCount.put(s.charAt(i), ++count); // changed to pre-increment
        } else {
            charCount.put(s.charAt(i), 1);
        }
```

Also note that I changed `count++` to `++count`, since `count++` returns the original value of count, so the value in the Map wouldn't change.

Comment: how can I make it work so it would print the first non-repeating char not any random non-repeating char?

Comment: @MonaJalal Replace `HashMap` with `LinkedHashMap`. This way the keys will be iterated in the order they were added to the Map.

Comment: @MonaJalal BTW, you should test for `if (charCount.get(ch)==1)`. The map doesn't have any entries with 0 value.

Comment: is use of LinkedHashMap necessary for order? because HashMap is also printing correctly

Comment: @MonaJalal HashMap doesn't guarantee order. The order is determined by the hashCodes of the keys (characters in your case). You may get correct output for some inputs, but you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: LinkedHashMap is very interesting. Thanks for introducing it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are iterating through charcount which has no element in it.

```
Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry: charCount.entrySet()
```